# How to find and replace the last space in each line of a file in BASH?

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed

I have a file like this:

```
Once upon a time there lived a cat.
The cat lived in the forest.
The forest had many trees.
```

I need to replace the last space per line with a "@", e.g.:

```
Once upon a time there lived a@cat.
The cat lived in the@forest.
The forest had many@trees.
```

I tried `sed 's/ .*$/@/g' file.txt`, but `.*` matches everything and deletes all of the text found there.

How can I replace the last space per line with "@"?

Comment: Ha ha, many ways to solve this little issue.  You see, regexp gives us way too many options :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) /\1@/'
```

Comment: If you do not like to escape the parentheses, you can do: `sed -r 's/(.*) /\1@/'`

Comment: why does this guarantee to replace only the last space?  i.e. why does `\(.*\)` match with the longest possible string that includes other spaces?

Comment: @cmo Because the `*` operator is matching *greedily*.  This means it is defined (and implemented) to match as much as possible (i. e. without letting the whole expression fail).  If you append a `?` operator to the `*` then the operator is not greedy anymore.  The `.` operator matches *any* character, including spaces.

Comment: That's a very important property; a more subtle feature I hadn't fully appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The regex to match the last space and nothing else is `(?=\S+$)`, not sure how to switch sed into PCRE mode (to support lookaheads):

```
perl -ple "s/ (?=\S+$)/@/" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use Perl for this:

```
perl -ple 's/ ([^ ]+)$/@\1/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
s/\s([^\s]*)$/@\1/g
```

Good luck, 
bob

EDIT: 
lol, tested it, seems to do what you want :)

```
my $s = "the quick brown fox jumped";
$s =~ s/\s([^\s]*)$/@\1/g;
print $s;
# prints the quick brown fox@jumped
```